# jquery.orgchart.js (caprica) Internet explorer 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following problem: I am using the javascript library Caprica jquery.orgchat.js ( https://github.com/caprica/jquery-orgchart ).

In Chrome,Firefox and Safari works great, but the problem is that which is going to run in internet explorer 10. In this browser, the organization chart takes about 3 minutes (often leaving the browser unanswered for long). In other browsers painting takes 5 seconds or less.

I tried changing the Compatibility View for IE7 , IE8 and IE9 and is the same.

Someone can help me out . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this one?